# Copying picture to /usr/share/backgrounds/ with a script

Tags: shell-script, shell, lightdm

I'm trying to copy a picture which gets selected with another script to `/usr/share/background/` so that I can use it with `lightdm`, but I can't get it to work. I tried the usual `cp "$file" /usr/share/background/wall.png` but that does not work.

Comment: What is the command and error message. "Does not work" can't be debugged in any reasonable way.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you review 2 things.

**1. Review the permissions**
If you're not running the script as root, then check the permissions.
/usr/share/backgrounds is owned by root and writing to it will require a super user action:

```
sudo cp "$file" /usr/share/backgrounds/wall.png
```

**2. Review the path**
If permissions are correct, then check the path.

The sample code you provided is trying to copy a file to **/usr/share/background**.
Try ammending it to the following:

```
cp "$file" /usr/share/backgrounds/wall.png
```

Note that there's an it's background**s** (plural).

Comment: The path was right in the script. How do I change the owner of the folder so that it's owned by the user and root?

Comment: Easiest way is to make the directory writable by the user's group with 2 steps: 1. chmod 0775 /usr/share/backgrounds/ 2. sudo chown root:usergroup